# Memory leak when malloc is called in a different function

Tags: c, memory, malloc, valgrind, free

The code looks something like this

```
void otherfunc(char* str) {
    str = malloc(128);
    // Initialize str to something
}

void mainfunc() {
    char* foo = NULL;
    
    otherfunc(foo);
    
    free(foo);
}
```

Ideally, `foo` should be freed, right? I'm not sure why this is leaking.
Also, if I move the `free()` to `otherfunc` it does not leak.

Comment: Running that code in a debugger would show you within seconds that `foo` is still `NULL` when you free it. You should get used to using a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the pointer by value, the pointer returned by malloc is lost when you exit the function, a correction to your code should be

```
void otherfunc(char** str) {
    *str = malloc(128);
    // Initialize str to something
}

void mainfunc() {
    char* foo = NULL;
    
    otherfunc(&foo);
    
    free(foo);
}
```